# Form onsubmit not working despite returning false

Tags: javascript, html

I cannot figure out why my form onsubmit function isn't working at all.  I am trying to create a form that validates a confirmation password, but I cannot get the onsubmit to call the function I created, although it seems to be written correctly.

```
<div class="container">
                <h2 class="py-2 page_title">Change Password for <%= user.username %>:</h2>
                <form onsubmit="return confirm_password();" class="form_content" action="/users/edit_password/<%= user._id %>?_method=PUT" method="POST">

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                            <input class="form-control" name="user[old_password]" placeholder="Old Password" type="password">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                            <input id="password" class="form-control" name="user[new_password]" placeholder="New Password" type="password">
                        </div>  
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">       
                        <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                            <input id="confirm_password" class="form-control" name="user[confirm_password]" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password">
                        </div>              
                    </div>

                    <button id="button" class="button zoom" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </div>
```

The Function

```
function confirm_password(){
    console.log("working");  //This doesn't happen, so I know it isn't even being called
    if (document.getElementById("password") != document.getElementById("confirm_password")){
        alert("Passwords Do Not Match");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

I have added an alert("working"); into the file to confirm that it is connected, and I am getting the alert.  However, after clicking submit, the console is telling me that "confirm_password" is not a function.  I have also tried adding a click listener to the button itself, and this too does not work either.  Is there something obvious I am just missing?  I have tried adding the script tag in the header and footer and this does not seem to change anything.

Thanks.

Comment: What does happen when you submit the form? Nothing, or does it submit without calling your function? Any errors in your console?

Comment: seems like the page reloads when you submit, have you tried to prevent the event?

Comment: When I click submit, nothing in the function seems to be called at all, the page just loads to where the "action" is called.  The console is telling me that "confirm_password" is not a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It conflicts with one of your  IDs here:

```
<input id="confirm_password"
```

Change the function name to something else like:

```
onsubmit="return confirmPassword(event);"
```

then:

```
function confirmPassword(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // your codes here
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it just seems that it is not calling the function at all.  Even when I add an alert at the beginning, nothing seems to happen.

Comment: Yes, so I put an alert in the js file to confirm that the file is connected, and I do get the alert.  However, after clicking submit, the console is telling me that "confirm_password" is not a function.  I am unsure why it would say that.

Comment: I've edited my answer, dont use underscore in naming functions, so do confirmPassword() instead of confirm_password()

Comment: Thank you so much, this seems to have worked!  I always thought the traditional naming of functions followed camelcase, I just didn't realize that an underscore would cause a problem.

Comment: underscore actually works, but it seem to have conflicted with this input ID:  <input id="confirm_password" class="form-control" name="user[confirm_password]" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password">

Comment: even if you use confirm_password as your function name, and change the input id to something else, it should work as well

Comment: Oh I see, I will have to be careful with what I name things.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you have to get your button as an element and add to it an event listener and then put your function in the scope of the event listner's callback

```
 <div class="container">
<h2 class="py-2 page_title">Change Password for <%= user.username %>:</h2>
      <form onsubmit="return confirm_password();" class="form_content" action="/users/edit_password/<%= user._id %>?_method=PUT" method="POST">

          <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                  <input class="form-control" name="user[old_password]" placeholder="Old Password" type="password">
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
              <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                  <input id="password" class="form-control" name="user[new_password]" placeholder="New Password" type="password">
              </div>  
          </div>
          <div class="row">       
              <div class="form-group col-lg-12">
                  <input id="Confirm_password" class="form-control" name="user[confirm_password]" placeholder="Confirm Password" type="password">
              </div>              
          </div>

          <button id="button" class="button zoom">Submit</button>
      </form>
  </div>

<script>
  const submitbutton =document.getElementsByClassName("button zoom")[0]
 submitbutton.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{

  confirm_password(e)

})

function confirm_password(e){
const passoword=document.getElementById("password").value 
 const password2=document.getElementById("Confirm_password").value
    if (passoword!=password2){
      e.preventDefault()
        alert("Passwords Do Not Match");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these solutions worked.  I added an alert in the js file to see if it was loading before or after the page loads, because I know that sometimes that could cause an issue.  It seems that the alert and load occurs before the page is loaded, even though the script is called after the rest of my html, would this cause an issue?

Comment: Okay, adding a click event listener to the button seems to have worked, but the page still tries to load the form action even after alerting me that the passwords don't match.  Is there a way to stop the page load from this?  Thanks.

Comment: This seems to have worked, when renaming my function to camelcase instead of using an underscore.  I guess that was the issue.  Thank you for your help!

Comment: yes also your if statement should compare the values retrieved from the elements

Comment: Yes, thank you so much for your help!  This all helped me get it to work.